# Do you need to use a separate $GOPATH between Windows and WSL?

Tags: go, gopath

I use Windows and WSL for developing Go code, but, don't know if I need to have a separate `$GOPATH` for Windows and WSL, or if I can use the same `$GOPATH` for both.

Can you use the same `$GOPATH` between Windows and WSL?

I am sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `GOPATH` env var in either environment. It was deprecated long ago - like over four years ago. You should no longer be setting it. Go modules are now the standard way to do what `GOPATH` was used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you use the same $GOPATH between Windows and WSL?

Yes, you even *should* use the same: **Unset** GOPATH on both.

(Just forget that GOPATH exists and stop reading things that still talk about GOPATH.)